# $L^p$ and $L^q$ spaces proof

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am studying for my final exam and I have found such a task:

> For every $p,q \in (1, \infty)$ we know that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Show that if $ f \in L^p(R)$ fulfills  $\int_{R}{f(x)g(x)}dx=0$ for every $g \in L^q(R)$ then $f=0$ almost everywhere.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any help would be useful.

Comment: You should use the fact $(L^p)^* = L^q$ and Hahn-Banach, I think.

Comment: I haven't been introduced to Hahn-Banach yet.

Comment: "For every $p,q \in (1, \infty)$ we know that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.": What??? This says that for example $1/3+1/3=1$; also $1/10+1/100=1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I guess the OP wants to say "For every $p,q \in (1, \infty)$ *such that* we know that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$..." I would be very surprised that someone who deals with $L^p$ spaces thinks that $1/3+1/3=1$ :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Well of course that's what was intended. My point was that the OP needs to write more carefully... ideally he'd _say_ what he meant, instead of making us guess.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I totally agree with your last sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint :**

Apply the hypothesis to
$$g=\mathrm{sign}(f) \times |f|^{\frac{p}{q}}$$

Comment: $0 = \int f g = \int sign(f) f |f|^{\frac{p}{q}} = \int |f|^{\frac{p}{q} + 1} = \int |f|^{p(\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p})} = \int |f|^p \implies |f| = 0$ a.e. Is that correct?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев Yes, it is. Thanks for sparing the OP to figure out the details by himself :)